# can anyone help me with candle counting script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to plot ema8, ema20 and sma20 with candle counter (i.e 1,2,3.....) whenever crossover occurs and counting end with another crossover or crossunder as per condition given.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='candle count', overlay=true,max_labels_count=10)

ema1 = ema(close,8)
ema2 = ema(close,20)
sma1 = sma(close,20)

// plot //
plot(ema1, color=red, linewidth=1, title="EMA 1")
plot(ema2, color=green, linewidth=1, title="EMA 2")
plot(sma1, color=black, linewidth=1, title="SMA 1")

count = 1

crossover = crossover(ema1,ema2)
crossunder = crossunder(ema2,sma1)

if crossover == crossover(ema1,ema2)
    for i = 1 to 10
    if crossunder == crossunder(ema2,sma1)
        break
    count := count + 1

label.new(bar_index,high, str.tostring(count), textcolor=color.blue, style=label.style_none)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='candle count', overlay=true,max_labels_count=10)

ema1 = ema(close,8)
ema2 = ema(close,20)
sma1 = sma(close,20)

// plot //
plot(ema1, color=red, linewidth=1, title="EMA 1")
plot(ema2, color=green, linewidth=1, title="EMA 2")
plot(sma1, color=black, linewidth=1, title="SMA 1")
    
var int count_over = 0
var int count_under = 0
    
crossover = ta.crossover(ema1,ema2)
crossunder = ta.crossunder(ema2,sma1)

if crossover
   count_over += 1
   count_under := 0
else if crossunder
   count_under += 1
   count_over := 0

plot(count_over)
plot(count_under)
```